# How to paste Tab character into Python interactive shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, paste

Today, I tried to paste "ip[tab]port" in a interpreter, the result is "ipport".

Example: Copy `111.222.3.44    80`(using spaces, here, in lieu of tab) from another source, e.g. Notepad, and paste it into the interactive shell. Unfortunately, when I try this, the [tab] doesn't 
paste, and the result is:`111.222.3.4480`

I would like to be able to paste the IP & Port with the [tab] so that they are properly separated when pasted.

Python 3.6, Windows OS.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share your code? Not sure what the issue is... (if you want to print a tab then `"bla\tbla"`) Is that what you mean?

Comment: look the edit ! :)

Comment: I also wanted to paste a tab into the Python 3 interactive shell (although I use Linux not Windows) and found that tabs get automatically removed as if they weren't in the copied text; e.g. copy `1 2 3` (numbers delimited by hard tabs) into the clipboard and when you paste into the shell you end up with `123`. As far as I can tell you can not paste a tab character into the Python shell although you can add them after pasting by editing the pasted text and pressing the tab key.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing, on Linux. It seems like the Python REPL just swallows all tab inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frustrating issue. The workaround I settled on was to paste into a text editor, then used `sed` to convert `tabs` into `\t` characters. Then copy and paste that into the python interactive shell.

For example:

1. Copy and paste `111.222.3.44[tab]80` into a text file that preserves the tabs, and save that file as `temp`.
2. Run a sed command to convert `tabs` into `\t`.

   `sed 's/\t/\\t/g' temp`
3. Copy and the result into the python interactive shell:

   `111.222.3.44\t80`

Answer (score -1):

`\t` is the tab delimiter in a string.

Ex:

```
>>> print("111.222.3.44\t80")
111.222.3.44   80
```

Comment: No this is not what i try to do =/

Comment: He's trying to figure out how to paste tab characters not print them.